# React Ant design Table is not visible although data is visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, frontend, antd

I am trying to create a table from ant design react I have copied an example but When I am trying to run it the output is not as expected.
Although I am using the same code can someone tell me what is the problem

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    filters: [
      {
        text: 'Joe',
        value: 'Joe',
      },
      {
        text: 'Category 1',
        value: 'Category 1',
        children: [
          {
            text: 'Yellow',
            value: 'Yellow',
          },
          {
            text: 'Pink',
            value: 'Pink',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: 'Category 2',
        value: 'Category 2',
        children: [
          {
            text: 'Green',
            value: 'Green',
          },
          {
            text: 'Black',
            value: 'Black',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    filterMode: 'tree',
    filterSearch: true,
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.includes(value),
    width: '30%',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    filters: [
      {
        text: 'London',
        value: 'London',
      },
      {
        text: 'New York',
        value: 'New York',
      },
    ],
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.startsWith(value),
    filterSearch: true,
    width: '40%',
  },
];
const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
  },
];

const onChange = (pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
  console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
};

const DataTable = () =>{
  return(
    <div className='data-table'>

<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} bordered/>
    </div>
  );
};



export default DataTable;
```

The table was supposed to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBbaL.png)

But the output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKG0U.png)

I was used the same code entered the same components I am unable to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Are the antd css being loaded on your application? It seems that the table is there but is missing the styles.

Comment: Where is the import section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the antd styles were missing. In order to load the styles correctly, add the following line to your index.js file.

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```